# i can't call a method with variables that are declared in a code block

Tags: java, variables

i can't call a method with variable that is declared in a code block. (like in my case a if statement in a for loop)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input;

        System.out.println("Enter 5 integers");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            input = scanner.nextInt();
            arrayList.add(input);
        }
        isSorted(arrayList);
    }

    public static void isSorted(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList) {
        boolean sorted;
        boolean dSorted;
        for (int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
            if (arrayList.get((i+1)) > arrayList.get(i)) {
                sorted = true;
            } else if (arrayList.get((i+1)) < arrayList.get(i)) {
                dSorted = true;
            } else {
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
        printResult(sorted, dSorted);
    }

    public static void printResult(boolean sorted, boolean dSorted) {
        if(sorted) {
            System.out.println("This set of numbers is sorted in ascending order.");
        } else if(dSorted) {
            System.out.println("This set of numbers is sorted in descending order.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This set of numbers is not sorted at all.");
        }
    }
}
```

compile error:

something like error:(33,21) java: variable sorted might not have been intialized

Comment: Replace `boolean sorted;` with `boolean sorted = false;`

Answer (score 0):

you should just initialize variable : sorted and dsorted

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you can not guarantee that both variables are getting initialized in the loop. It depends on the list that is passed to the method.

Therefore you have to initialize those variables (probably false).